# C++ cursor changes to hour glass using WM_SETCURSOR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, cursor

OK i have a game when person loses ill set a different cursor. i used the setcursro with loadcusor and WM_SETCURSOR. the problem is that my default cursor which i hae set it where i register my window, it changes to hour glass until the person loses than it changes to the cursor i have set it to. i found that when i use the WM_SETCURSOR it changes the default cusor to hour glass until i set it to a different cursor when person loses. im using win32
any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally if you're going to change cursors much, you want to do something like:

First we initialize the cursors we'll use:

```
HCURSOR cursors[3];

cursors[0] = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);    // default cursor
cursors[1] = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);    // other cursor
cursors[2] = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT);     // wait cursor

int current_cursor = 0;
```

When we want to change the cursor we just pick the one we want:

```
current_cursor = 1;
```

And our WM_SETCURSOR handler looks something like this:

```
case WM_SETCURSOR:
    SetCursor(cursors[current_cursor]);
    return TRUE;
```