# WIn32: Show custom cursor only in client area

Tags: c++, winapi, window, cursor

Is there a way to show custom cursor only in client area? I'd like to show standard Windows resize cursors when user wants to resize the window and and normal arrow when mouse is on the title bar.

Basically the cursor should behave on non-client area like it behaves in an application which does not have a custom cursor.

My idea of `WM_SETCURSOR` handling is below.

```
    case WM_SETCURSOR:
    {
        if (m_showMouseCursor)
        {
            if(LOWORD(lParam) == HTCLIENT)
            {
                SetCursor(m_cursor); //Use custom cursor
            }
            else
            {
                //Not in client area -
                //what I have to call here?
            }
            ShowCursor(true);
            return true;
         }
    }
    break;
```

In an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560201/c-cursor-changes-to-hour-glass-using-wm-setcursor) the changing of cursors is made by handling all the used cursors explicitly. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to implement this?

Comment: Just `return false` to say you haven't processed the message, to let `DefWindowProc` get on with what it normally does.

Comment: This is even stated in comments on the `WM_SETCURSOR` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382.aspx): *"In most cases you should only set the cursor if LOWORD(lParam) is HTCLIENT, meaning the client area of the window. For the nonclient area, let Windows set the cursor."*